# Keep null values – Java POJO to org.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, org.json

I am creating a RESTful API service in Java using Spring Boot. I have a class from which I am trying to create a JSON Object. Everything is working great - except the json object from the class instance is omitting the null values. I would like to keep the keys and have the value set to null, rather than stripping them completely from the output.

#### The output is as follows (shortened for brevity)

```
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "question1",
            "svg": "svg1",
            "questionNum": 1
        },
        {
            "question": "question2"
            "svg": "q2",
            "questionNum": 2
        }
    ],
```

#### Preferred output

```
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "question1",
            "svg": "svg1",
            "questionNum": 1, 
            "shuffledNum": null, 
            "answer": null

        },
        {
            "question": "question2"
            "svg": "q2",
            "questionNum": 2,
            "shuffledNum": null,
            "answer": null 
        }
    ],
```

#### Here is the JsonQuestionObject:

```
public class JsonQuestionObject {

    private Integer questionNum;
    private String svg;
    private Integer shuffledNum = null;
    private String question;
    private Integer answer = null;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

#### Here is the JSON Creator method (which takes an array of JsonQuestionObjects)

```
public JSONObject createQuestionsJson(ArrayList<JsonQuestionObject> questions) {
    JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray content = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject subContent = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray qarray = new JSONArray();


    for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
        JsonQuestionObject q = questions.get(i);
        Integer qnum = q.getQuestionNum();
        JSONObject qitem = new JSONObject(q);

        if (qnum < 5) {
            qarray.put(qitem);
        } else if (qnum > 4 && qnum < 7) {
            qarray.put(qitem);
        } else if (qnum > 6 && qnum < 9 ) {
            qarray.put(qitem);
        } else if (qnum > 8 &&) {
            qarray.put(qitem);
        }
    }
    subContent.put("questions", qarray);
    content.put(subContent);
    output.put("output", content);

    return output;
}
```

Is there any way of keeping these null values other than creating the JSONObject manually by using the setters & getters of each property and setting `JSONObject.put("answer", JSONObject.NULL)` ?

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you create new `JSONObject` with constructor `public JSONObject(Object bean)` all `null` values are skipped by internal implementation. To keep `null`-s you have to create and populate new `JSONObject` by yourself.

From other side, you do not need to use `org.json.*` library. You can construct similar structure using `Map`s and `List`s. See below structure:

```
JsonQuestionObject[] questionArray = {new JsonQuestionObject()};
HashMap<String, Object> questions = new HashMap<>();
questions.put("questions", questionArray);

List<Object> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
questionsList.add(questions);

Map<String, Object> result = Collections.singletonMap("output", questionsList);
```

You can return `Map` in your method and it will be automatically serialised to `JSON`. You can enable nulls using `Spring Boot` properties or add `JsonInclude` annotation:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class JsonQuestionObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always` to your `application.properties`.

Also, take a look on other settings from `spring.jackson` family for other settings of JSON serialization.

Comment: I tried to add it, but it does nothing. Are there any extra dependencies to add for this to work? Seems like I am not using jackson at all, since i am using the org.json dependencies?

Comment: @user2868900, sorry, I never works with `org.json` library - I use `jackson`. Only one thins what I can suggest is look for serializer settings - I guess, it should have similar parameters.